# looking for vehicles 1939-41

Tags: sound-effects, sound-libraries, sfx, effects

hi guys, i'm hoping someone will be able to help me out.

i've got a mini series set in 1941 canada and i'm looking for north american vehicles from the 1939 to 1941 range.

sound effect recordings for cars like (or similar to)...

cadillac series 62/
Packard 120/
FORD Mercury Club Coupe ; Town Sedan; Marmon-Herrington sedan/ 
Chevrolet Master DeLuxe; Convertible Coupe;  Fleetline/
Buick Special Series Touring Sedan/
Chrysler Sedan; Royal/
Plymouth 2door Sedan.

i've also some *large trucks* and *military vehicles* that i need to find sound for as well.

i'll only need the usual standard stuff (start, idle, away / in, idle, off / pass bys: gravel & asphalt)

if there's someone who knows their vintage vehicles i could send some screen shots to, so i can find out what make some of these are, it would help me in tracking down the sounds i'll need.

if you own recordings, or can point me in the right direction to some sounds, i would really appreciate it.

cheers for this,

P.

Answer (score 3):

Hi pepe,

While at Sounddogs.com some years ago I mastered the Masters Workshop vintage car collection for the in-house library.

They have a 34 Rolls, 39 Packard and more.  Not perfect matches but perhaps useful.

The recordings are older (DAT), but they were recorded exceptionally well.  Masters Workshop (a post facility in Toronto) had a recordist (Jamie, I think?) who was very skilled at recording cars.  The recordings are clean and thorough.  They are I believe 48/16.

I cut them by perspective and also maneuver (i.e. up, away, by) so they are organized and should be easy to cut in.

Here's the link to the library on Sound Dogs.  There are a few pages you'll have to flip through:
http://www.sounddogs.com/searchresults.asp?Keyword=workshop

If you are thinking about buying, contact Rob Nokes, Sounddogs.com's owner, directly.  He assembles custom libraries and will likely give you a break on price.

Paul Virostek

Comment: cheers paul. i saw and heard the packard at sounddogs (liked it), but i'll check the workshop collection as well. thanks for the tip.
P.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbit ears audio did a series of tanks and APCs that may be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

thanks Rene.  If you need Military Vehicles, we did a large collection of tanks and APCS with tons of exterior coverage and 6-8 channels on board each vehicle:

http://rabbitearsaudio.com/rea005-military-vehicles/

Michael

Answer (score 0):

For the military trucks try the Deuce and a Half from Soundstorm.